# get-job output is error

Tags: powershell, powercli

```
$list = Get-Cluster
      foreach ($view in $list){
                   Write-Host "Checking on :  $view"
                   [string]$Obj = ($view.MoRef.Type + "-" + $View.MoRef.value)  
                   [string]$bx = ($VC + ":" + $Obj)
                   $vcdata = [ordered]@{
                                       Obj = $obj                 
                                       Name = $view.name
                                       ID = $bx
                                       Name = $VCServerName
                                      DC = Get-Datacenter -Cluster 
                                     }
         }
get-job | Receive-Job -Keep | select Obj, Name, ID, Name, DC
```

I get the below message along with output

> Method invocation failed because [VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.VIServerImpl] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System
>   .Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

Comment: Please edit your code to make it readable.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

powershell thinks you want to add those objects. Iso

```
[string]$Obj = ($view.MoRef.Type + "-" + $View.MoRef.value)
[string]$bx = ($VC + ":" + $Obj)
```

Try

```
[string]$Obj = "$($view.MoRef.Type)-$($View.MoRef.value)"
[string]$bx = "$($VC):$($Obj)"
```

Comment: Working great, but am also getting the below how do I exclude it from my output, tried applying filter and not working. 

System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System .Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce, but "Get-Cluster" "is not recognized as a cmdlet". What are "$VC", "$VCServerName" and "get-job"?

Comment: What is the use of the foreach?   When it's finished, $vcdata contains only the last element of the cluster list.

Comment: It's need powercli to be installed and snapins to be added for executing get-cluster,Just saw that.Filter shows all the messages on the screen, but when I export it to csv it get me only the data I selected